# Adding child controls to a WrapPanel

Tags: c#, wpf

*I am very much new to WPF.*

I have a very simple problem.

I have a stackpanel spTerminalBox.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="881*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="11*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="156"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="371*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <my:WindowHeader x:Name="title" Title="Internet Cafe management software (ICM)"   CloseClicked="window_CloseClicked"   VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
    <StackPanel Name ="spTerminalBox" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,10,10,20"/>
</Grid>
```

My xaml structure is that.

I am filling a user control in that stackpanel dynamically in code.
Once if child elements on a StackPanel do not fit in the StackPanel area, then it should not go outside of the visible area, it should come down.

How to achieve this ?

Comment: What do you mean by "come down"?

Comment: After filling say 5 controls if no space, then 6 th has to come in next line in stackpanel

Comment: StackPanel shouldn't be used to achieve a behavior you described. You can try WrapPanel or write your own custom panel.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTestBench.PanelSample"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="PanelSample" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <WrapPanel Name="MyPanel" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Codebehind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfTestBench
{
    public partial class PanelSample
    {
        public PanelSample()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                MyPanel.Children.Add(new Rectangle
                {
                    Width = 100,
                    Height = 20,
                    StrokeThickness = 1,
                    Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
                    Margin = new Thickness(5)
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Execution result:

[image: Wide] [image: Narrow]

Comment: How can we add two controls(textbox+label) at a time as a single children. In the above example you are adding rectangle for 5 times like that I want to add rectangle+label(as single children) for 5 times

Comment: @Surya In WPF all controls can be nested.  For example you can make another stackpanel, add the textblock and label to that stackpanel, then add the stackpanel to the wrappanel as a single control.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 5):

you should use a `WrapPanel` for your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `StackPanel` in a `ScrollViewer` and call `ScrollIntoView()` on the element you just added.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `StackPanel` and adding `UserControls` use `ListBox` which you'll
bind  to an [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
The 'ObservableCollection' will notify the ListBox when items are added/removed.
Change the ListBox.ItemsPanel to be `Wrappanel` instead of `StackPanel`

taken from [http://wpftutorial.net/](http://wpftutorial.net/WrapPanel.html)
`"The wrap panel is similar to the StackPanel but it does not just stack all child elements to one row, it wraps them to new lines if no space is left. The Orientation can be set to Horizontal or Vertical."`

you Xaml should look like this:

```
<ListBox  x:Name="MyListBox"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource UserControlsObservableCollection}}"                                  
          HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
              <WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

it will  be better to use  for your case it has an attached property ready for this but StackPanel will work in FIFO

> DockPanel

```
for example 

            Button btn = new Button();
            DockPanel.SetDock(btn,Dock.Bottom);
            dockPanelTerminalBox.Children.Add(btn);
```

but if you want just use this in your code behind

```
spTerminalBox.Children.Add("yourControl");
```

Comment: Yes i did that. Prob lies in visibility of controls once it goes out of stack panel width.I need it to not go out of box. I has to come below