# Creating a textbox in xaml through xaml.cs code

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I want to create textboxes in xaml file upon a button click through the .xaml.cs file from a loop (probably). I've calculated the margins for each textbox to appear in the panel but do not know how to bind the code. [Here's the image of the xaml design view and what I'm trying to achieve. The window will have one textbox for choices appear and the loop will create another and another each time the add choice button is clicked.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7Tzo.png)

Can anyone please help? I'm just learning wpf. Thank you

Comment: what mean by **bind the code**? recommend a book [Applications = Code + Markup](http://www.charlespetzold.com/wpf/)

Comment: @LeiYang I mean the code in the .xaml.cs file should create a corresponding action in the .xaml file

Comment: Then what have you tried

Comment: Searched but can't find anything about creating a new component from the cs code. Honestly have no clue how to go about it. Any hint or example or anything would be helpful

Comment: @LeiYang The link you gave isn't the full book. I'd have to buy it?

Comment: Try google it, there's many.

Comment: @ElizabethEkefre: I posted an answer to guide you. Use the Children property of the panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming by *Bind the code* you mean how to add the `TextBox` to the panel. To do that, you need to add the textboxes to the `Children` property of the panel.

If you need to do this upon initialization of your form, then just place your code after `InitializeComponent();` in the form constructor.

Here's an example how to do this programatically, responding to a click event:

Xaml:

```
<StackPanel Name="pn_Content" Orientation="Vertical">
    <Button Click="btn_Add_TextBox_Click">Add Textbox</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

C#:

```
private void btn_Add_TextBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
   TextBox tb = new TextBox();
   tb.Height = 23;
   tb.Width = 100;
   pn_Content.Children.Add(tb);
}
```

and that's it.

Comment: Thanks alot I just needed that little example for guidance :] really helped

Answer (score 0):

First, place all the current text boxes in a container, for example a stack panel named stackPanel.
Then add your controls to the Children of the panel:

```
stackPanel.Children.Add(new TextBox { Text = "TextBox" });
```

please refer to these questions:

[WPF: How to dynamically Add Controls in dynamically created WPF Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884185/wpf-how-to-dynamically-add-controls-in-dynamically-created-wpf-window)

[Adding child controls in Stackpanel WPF C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20350465/adding-child-controls-in-stackpanel-wpf-c-sharp)